# Is it possible to include LaTeX into Sphinx?

Tags: latex, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

The Sphinx Titlepage can be customized in conf.py with "latex_elements" and the "preamble" directive but i cant find a solution to include normal latex source code into sphinx. The reason is that i want to customize some pages of the document with latex.

Is there a way to include Latex-Code in the body of an document?

(I've define a latex-"newcommand" in the preamble in conf.py but dont know how to call it in sphinx)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it 2 ways:

The first way is that you can define it when you use it:

```
My raw code:
.. raw:: latex

     code here
```

The other way is that you can define it at the end of the file and use it:

```
My raw code: |rawcode|

.. |rawcode| raw:: latex

     codehere
```

Answer (score 0):

In `conf.py` you can define a new command like `/newcommand{\newCom}{...}`.

In a sphinx text file this command can be referenced with:

```
.. raw:: latex

        \newCom
```

Crucial was the **newline** after the ".. raw:: latex" command, it seems as if omitting that was the issue.

Comment: A directive starts with two dots, a space, a directive name, two colons, at least one space, then the arguments which can be on multiple subsequent lines, then options oin the form of ":optionname: optionvalue" on separated lines, then an empty line, then the directive's content.  Read the official specific here: https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html